# How to programmatically raise SizeChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mstest

I'm trying to execute code in a SizeChangedEventHandler but the following is not working:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSizeChanged()
{
    var panel = new System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel();

    bool handled = false;
    panel.SizeChanged += (o, e) =>
    {
        handled = true; // how to get this to be executed
    };

    panel.Width = 100; // naive attempt to change size!

    Assert.IsTrue(handled);
}
```

I originally tried to use the RaiseEvent method but I was not been able to supply it with the correct xxxEventArgs type, due to not knowing the constructor arguments and the object browser is not helping:

```
panel.RaiseEvent(new System.Windows.SizeChangedEventArgs()) // does not compile
```

Obviously, the above test serves no purpose but I'm after correct way of getting the event to fire in a unit-tested environment.

Comment: Why are you adding this as a unit test? Are you testing to see what the window changes are or are you testing the logic of the code called when resizing?

Comment: @BenSteele yes, the latter. I could move stuff around in the code but have been stubbornly trying to test as-is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very strange that the SizeChanged event doesn't fire with your code, it appears to be correct. Maybe the StackPanel doesn't exists in the visual tree because it's not really shown on the screen, so the event is never fired.
Try to show a real window with a StackPanel on the screen, and programmatically change his width or height.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSizeChanged()
    {
        Window wnd = new Window();
        wnd.Content = new System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel();

        bool handled = false;
        wnd.SizeChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            handled = true; // how to get this to be executed
        };

        wnd.Show();
        wnd.Width = 100; // naive attempt to change size!

        Assert.IsTrue(handled);

    }
```

You can't use the RaiseEvent method, because SizeChanged is not a RoutedEvent.

Comment: If you go down that route, i think you may have to change wnd.ActualWidth rather than the width as stated:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, ActualWidth is a read-only property. You can only modify Width value, but to get the SizeChanged event fired, you need to show the Window on the screen

Comment: I tested my code above, and I confirm that SizeChanged event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

Using the below reflection you can succeed:

```
//panel =>System.Windows.Controls.Panel instance..
SizeChangedInfo sifo = new SizeChangedInfo(panel, new Size(0, 0), true, true);
SizeChangedEventArgs ea = typeof(System.Windows.SizeChangedEventArgs).GetConstructors(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault().Invoke(new object[] {(panel as FrameworkElement),sifo }) as SizeChangedEventArgs;
ea.RoutedEvent = Panel.SizeChangedEvent;
panel.RaiseEvent(ea);
```